# Spring Boot OpenAPI 3 - How to pass the Pagination Details?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm looking to develop the **Spring Boot + OpenAPI 3** example by taking a look at the https://www.dariawan.com/tutorials/spring/documenting-spring-boot-rest-api-springdoc-openapi-3/ and https://techsparx.com/software-development/openapi/spring-boot-rest-api-docs.html.  In this example, I am looking to pass the pagination details through Swagger UI that I got by adding the `springdoc-openapi-ui`.

What Spring Boot Configurations do I need to do in order to support custom pagination.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add @PageableAsQueryParam annotation on the method 
and add springdoc-openapi-data-rest as a dependency

Answer (score 4):

Their is more than one possiblity the simpliest and fastest is if only want to enable the support of spring Pageable Type, you can just enable it using:

```
SpringDocUtils.getConfig().replaceWithClass(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable.class,
org.springdoc.core.converters.models.Pageable.class);
```

Alternately, the projects that use Pageable type can aslo add the follwing dependency together with the springdoc-openapi-ui dependency. This dependency enables the support of spring-data-rest types as well: @RepositoryRestResource and QuerydslPredicate annotations.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

And the add @ParameterObject on the Pageable object on your controller method.

```
 @GetMapping("/books")
 public ResponseEntity<List<BookDTO>> getBooks(@ParameterObject Pageable pageable)
```

Answer (score 4):

"The support for Pageable of spring-data-commons is available out-of-the box since springdoc-openapi v1.6.0. For this, you have to combine `@ParameterObject` annotation with the `Pageable` type." - [Source](https://springdoc.org/#how-can-i-map-pageable-spring-data-commons-object-to-correct-url-parameter-in-swagger-ui)

Assuming you are using springdoc-openapi v1.6.0 or grater, you could do something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/foo")
public Page<Foo> getFoo(@ParameterObject Pageable pageable) {
  // do something
}
```